# Showing more than 5 items under recent items SharePoint 2013 Quick Launch

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, quick-launch

In SharePoint 2013 site. the quick launch navigation shows 5 items by default in the recent items. And we need to increase that number to 8 or 10. I don't find any out of the box ways to do that and even google is not helping. Could you please suggest How we could achieve this.Is there any third party tool or any custom scripts We may use to do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good question.  I checked myself and was unable to add an additional recent link.  I also did a trawl to try and find a post that covers this, but have drawn a blank.  The only other thing I can think of is to add commonly-used links to either the quick launch or else the 'top bar' navigation.  Could it be that you have lots of site contents in the site collection (e.g. a departmental site) and so users are accessing numerous different lists and doc libraries?  Or could it be that the top bar navigation needs updating, so users don't need to rely on the Recent links?

Answer (score 0):

It is by default that the quick launch navigation cannot show more than 5 items in the recent items.

I don't think we can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Follow below steps-->

1. Go to Site settings
2. Then go to Navigation settings
3. Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting
4. Then go to Current Navigation
5. Add heading , it will give you browse option.
6. Browse your list/library/page and select , and add a title.
7. Your browsed item will be available at left navigation.